# (JQuery/JavaScript) Filter table by 15, 50, 100, 500 or show all records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I've got an example of filter by Group name and Number of records to show.

I want to be able to filter instead of keep appending and appending, the filter should only show the amount of records selected e.g. 15, 50, 100, 500 or All records. When selecting 15 then selecting 100 it will keep the 15 records and append the 100 aswell.

It should work like:

`Select` 15 it should show 15 records.

Then `select` 100 it should Keep 15 records then should add 75 records.

Then `select` 50 it should remove 50 records.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong here?

```js
// Get all group names
GetPatientGroupNames();
// Get all patients
GetPatientListData();

// On page select initialize functions
$(document).ready(function() {
  // On select group, change midwives last sync list to the selected group
  $('#selectGroupInput').change(function(sender) {
    // Get all group names
    GetPatientGroupNames();
    // Get all patients
    GetPatientListData();
    var MyObject = {};
    MyObject.PatientID = "1";
    MyObject.patientFirstname = "Test";
    MyObject.patientSurname = "TestLastName";
    MyObject.patientNHSID = "FGFGD345";
    MyObject.Name = "Team1";
    ShowPatientTable(MyObject, $('#selectGroupInput option:selected').text(), $('#selectNumberOfRecords option:selected').text());
  });

  // On show record number, change midwives last sync list to the selected number of records
  $('#selectNumberOfRecords').change(function(sender) {

    // Get all group names
    GetPatientGroupNames();
    // Get all patients
    GetPatientListData();

    var MyObject = {};
    MyObject.PatientID = "1";
    MyObject.patientFirstname = "Test";
    MyObject.patientSurname = "TestLastName";
    MyObject.patientNHSID = "FGFGD345";
    MyObject.Name = "Team1";

    ShowPatientTable(MyObject, $('#selectGroupInput option:selected').text(), $('#selectNumberOfRecords option:selected').text());
  });
});

function GetPatientGroupNames() {
  // Set time before records start to load on page
  if (document.getElementById('selectGroupInput') !== null) {
    var GroupSelectOptions = document.getElementById('selectGroupInput').options;
    for (i = GroupSelectOptions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) GroupSelectOptions[i] = null;
    var GroupSelectInput = document.getElementById('selectGroupInput');

    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'All';
    opt.innerHTML = 'All';
    GroupSelectInput.appendChild(opt);

    var MyObject = {};
    MyObject.Name = "Team1";

    // Check to see if response message returns back "OK"

    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = JSON.stringify(MyObject);
    opt.innerHTML = MyObject['Name'];
    GroupSelectInput.appendChild(opt);

    // Check to see if there is a input with the id of selectGroup
    if (document.getElementById('selectGroupInput')) {

      if ((document.getElementById('selectGroupInput')).selectedIndex != null) {
        var Selectelement = document.getElementById('selectGroupInput');

        if ((Selectelement.options[Selectelement.selectedIndex]).value != "All") {
          currentArray = JSON.parse((Selectelement.options[Selectelement.selectedIndex]).value);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Get all patient information for patient list, and append to patient list table (Patient List page)
function GetPatientListData() {

  var MyObject = {};
  MyObject.PatientID = "1";
  MyObject.patientFirstname = "Test";
  MyObject.patientSurname = "TestLastName";
  MyObject.patientNHSID = "FGFGD345";
  MyObject.Name = "Team1";

  ShowPatientTable(MyObject, $('#selectGroupInput option:selected').text(), $('#selectNumberOfRecords option:selected').text());
}

// Show patient table with populated list of patients 
function ShowPatientTable(MyObject, GroupName, NumberRecords) {


  $(".patientListHiddenNotice").css("display", "none");
  // Stored patient list table rows
  var patientTableRecord = [];
  var patientTableRecordCounter = 0;

  if (MyObject) {
    // Add new patient list to be displayed in table
    // Set group input back to all when live searching

    // If so, loop through the old Patient list
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

      if (GroupName == "All") {
        // Show team column
        $('.showAllTeam').show();

        // If so, push the Patient into the new list
        patientTableRecord[patientTableRecordCounter++] = '<tr id="' + MyObject["PatientID"] + '"><td class="patientListNames">' + MyObject["patientFirstname"] + ' ' + MyObject["patientSurname"] + '(' + MyObject["patientNHSID"] + ')' + '</td><td>' + MyObject["Name"] + '</td></tr>';
      } else {
        // Hide team table column if user has selected a group name in group drop down menu
        $('.showAllTeam').hide();
        // Check if the filter matches the Patient being checked
        if ((MyObject["Name"]).toLowerCase().indexOf(GroupName.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
          // Append patient data to the list of patients table
          patientTableRecord[patientTableRecordCounter++] = '<tr id="' + MyObject["PatientID"] + '"><td class="patientListNames">' + MyObject["patientFirstname"] + ' ' + MyObject["patientSurname"] + '(' + MyObject["patientNHSID"] + ')' + '</td></tr>';
        }
      }
    }
  }





  // Check if array exists or is empty
  if (patientTableRecord === undefined || patientTableRecord.length == 0) {
    // If there are no Patients to show, notify the user
    $(".patientListHiddenNotice").css("display", "none");
    $(".patientListEmptyNotice").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".patientListHiddenNotice").css("display", "none");
    $(".patientListEmptyNotice").css("display", "none");
  }

  // Check that there are actually Patients to display
  if (patientTableRecord.length) {
    // When user selected all, 
    if (NumberRecords === "All") {
      NumberRecords = patientTableRecord.length;
    }

    // Check if the new Patient array is too large
    if (patientTableRecord.length > NumberRecords) {
      // If so, chop off all records over the limit, and update the "Patients Hidden" footer
      $(".recordsHidden").text(patientTableRecord.length - NumberRecords);
      $(".patientListHiddenNotice").css("display", "block");
      $(".patientListEmptyNotice").css("display", "none");

      patientTableRecord.splice(NumberRecords, patientTableRecord.length - NumberRecords);
    }
  } else {
    // If there are no Patients to show, notify the user
    $(".patientListEmptyNotice").css("display", "block");
  }

  // Show patient records
  $('#patientListTable').find('tbody').append(patientTableRecord);
}
```

```css
/* Hidden Patient Notice */

.patientListHiddenNotice {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F3E88E;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* No Patients Found Notice */

.patientListEmptyNotice {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F3E88E;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <!-- /.panel-heading -->
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
          <!-- Order patient list by --> <b>Order by</b>

          <div class="btn-group inline" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <!-- Order by group name -->
            <div class="btn-group btn-sm" role="group">
              <select class="btn btn-default" id="selectGroupInput"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Show number of patient records --> <b>Show records</b>

          <div class="btn-group inline" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <div class="btn-group btn-sm" role="group">
              <select class="btn btn-default" id="selectNumberOfRecords">
                <option>15</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
                <option>500</option>
                <option>All</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
          <!-- Patient listing table responsive wrapper -->
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <!-- Patient listing table -->
            <table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="patientListTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="sortable orderNameByASC">Patients</th>
                  <th class="showAllTeam">Team Name</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="patientListHiddenNotice">
              <h4><span class='recordsHidden'>0</span> records hidden, use search field above...</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="patientListEmptyNotice">
              <h4>No records found</h4>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rggam5dd/)

Comment: This kind of thing is much easier with a MV-whatever data-binding approach, using something like knockout or angular

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @JSantosh I've provided you with a fiddle. Check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), so you keep adding more rows instead of replacing the rows that are there.

You can simply change it to:

```
$('#patientListTable').find('tbody').html(patientTableRecord);
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Lsun3f/)**

Comment: I think the issue here is that sometimes it is an append (when the table is growing) and sometimes a replace (when the table is shrinking.)

I think I'd cut through the complexity and write the table from scratch each time with .html() more or less as suggested.

Comment: `.html` seems to be alot slower than `.append` - so when I end up putting in around 800+ records and try and load it on a iPad or any other devices the table like freezes the page because the rendering quite slow. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett You could try `.empty().append(patientTableRecord);` instead of `html()`, since it is logically the same; although I don't know if it would perform better. You could also possibly do `$('#patientListTable').find('tbody').children().detach();` before appending it, but you might be creating a memory leak.

Comment: @Stryner I've gone with the method of `$('#patientListTable').find('tbody').children().detach();` before appending the data to table

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic.

```js
$('#selectNumberOfRecords').change(function() {
  GenerateTableData($(this).val())
})
GenerateTableData($('#selectNumberOfRecords option:selected').val())

function GenerateTableData(NoOfRecordsRequested) {
  var temp = ''
  var ExistingRecords = $('#table >tbody >tr').length;

  // If the requested records are less  than existing records then we remove the extra records else we add the remaining records (not all , only remaining records for ex: 15 records are presnt if requested are 100 then we add next 75 only.)
  if (ExistingRecords > NoOfRecordsRequested) {
    $('#table >tbody >tr').slice(-(ExistingRecords - NoOfRecordsRequested)).remove()
  } else {
    for (i = ExistingRecords+1; i <= NoOfRecordsRequested; i++) {
      temp += '<tr><td>team-' + i + '</td></tr>'
    }
    $('#table >tbody').append(temp)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="btn btn-default" id="selectNumberOfRecords">
  <option value='15'>15</option>
  <option value='50'>50</option>
  <option value='100'>100</option>
  <option value='500'>500</option>
</select>
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When I try this method, it doesn't remove the current table records like I wanted. It sometimes duplicates the records. Then sometimes it doesn't even change the number of records shown.

Comment: i didn't find any duplicates , and it is removing records , try 15 , 50 , 100 then 15 . you'll see 15 non duplicate records . and also try 15 , 500, the balance 485 records are appended without removing first 15.

Comment: Could we continue this in a chat room?